# Issues when making a nested dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
infected_channels = {
    'channelID': {
        'infected' : True,
        'userID': ''
    },
    'channelID': {
        'infected': True,
        'userID': ''
    },
    'channelID': {
        'infected': True,
        'userID': ''
    }
}
```

Hey,

I'm currently making a discord bot, whenever someone talks in a channel they `infect` it, basically i need to create a  nest (i think is the term) for every person that talks in a channel. The example above will contain nothing to begin with, until someone speaks in the selected channel, however im unsure how to make a nest programatically. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can place any object you want into a dictionary.
To create a nested dictionary, you would do the following:

```
infected_channels = {}
...
new_channel = {'infected': True, 'userID': ''}
infected_channels['channelID'] = new_channel
```

This would result in the following dictionary:

```
{
    'channelID': {
        'infected' : True,
        'userID': ''
    },
}
```

Comment: Oh wow, thats alot simpler than I thought. Thank you for explaining this to me :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a empty list and then add whenever you need to.

```py
infected_channels = {}

def add():
  infected_channels['channelID'] = {'infected': true, 'userID': ''}

add()
```